# Can ack be coerced into searching a complicated project

Tags: makefile, project, ack

ack is a great tool for searching, especially if everything you want to find is in nested directories below a top project dir.

I'd like to search a number of different directory trees, in order to search my whole project.

I could do something like this (there are 5 or 6 more directories I'd include):

```
ack sometext . ../../Libraries/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/ ../../Libraries/CMSIS/
```

I've also tried doing it via the makefile, where I'd make ack a phony target, invoking ack on the directories Makefile knows about. This works, but the syntax to invoke it is unfortunate:

```
gmake ack SVAL=sometext
```

where in the Makefile:

```
ack:
    $(ACK) $(SVAL) $(LIB_DIRS) $(DEVICE_DIRS) $(OTHER_PROJECT_DIRS)
```

Ideally, there would be something I could embed in the .ackrc to define the directories that ack searches. Anyone have a favorite way to use ack to search a complicated project directory structure?

Comment: Let me rephrase it, you are looking a way to set directories in `ackrc` file and let `ack` read them from there instead of writing them again and again from command line. Is like that?

Comment: That is correct. My understanding, though, is that ack gives you a way to ignore certain directories via the .ackrc, but not the reverse.

Comment: Well, I don't know how to achieve what you are looking for but there is an option `-G REGEX` that lets you use a `perl` regex, which are very powerful, to select the directories to include. If all your directories have a common path you could work with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ack can do what I want, with a complicated command line.  My best answer to date is to embed it in a bash script, so I would type:

```
./pack foobar
```

To search my entire project for foobar.

The script pack would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTEXT=-C1
c:/bin/ack $CONTEXT $* . ../../Libraries/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/ \
../../Libraries/CMSIS/
```

Still would prefer a .ackrc solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sack: wrapper for grep, ack and/or ag (silver searcher)
http://sampsonchen.com/sack/

Can switch your `search environment' using pre-set profiles, sets up the CL flags and preset target (MULTIPLE) top-level starting-point directorieS